# What does a reference-to-reference mean in C++? (Not an rvalue reference)

Tags: c++, reference

suppose I have

```
typedef int& intr;
typedef intr& intrr;
```

I am allowed to declare

```
int x = 7;
intrr y = x;
```

But what *is* a reference-to-reference? Is an intrr any different semantically than just an intr?

Comment: hmm, another related question: [Concise explanation of reference collapsing rules requested: (1) A& & -> A& , (2) A& && -> A& , (3) A&& & -> A& , and (4) A&& && -> A&&](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13725747)

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a reference to reference. The C++ standard explicitly says so:

§8.3.3/5

> There shall be no references to references, ...

In typedefs and templates, there is a rule commonly referred to as "reference collapsing". It's described in paragraph 6 of the same section:

> If a typedef (7.1.3), a type *template-parameter* (14.3.1), or a
>   *decltype-specifier* (7.1.6.2) denotes a type `TR` that is a reference to a type `T`, an attempt to create the type “lvalue reference to *cv*
>   `TR`” creates the type “lvalue reference to `T`”, while an attempt to
>   create the type “rvalue reference to *cv* `TR`” creates the type `TR`.
>
> [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> int i;
> typedef int& LRI;
> typedef int&& RRI;
>
> LRI& r1 = i;           // r1 has the type int&
> const LRI& r2 = i;     // r2 has the type int&
> const LRI&& r3 = i;    // r3 has the type int&
>
> RRI& r4 = i;           // r4 has the type int&
> RRI&& r5 = 5;          // r5 has the type int&&
>
> decltype(r2)& r6 = i;  // r6 has the type int&
> decltype(r2)&& r7 = i; // r7 has the type int&
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

`intr` and `intrr` in your sample are exactly the same type, which is `int&`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    typedef int& intr;
    typedef intr& intrr;
    int x = 7;
    intrr y = x;
    std::cout << std::is_same<intr, intrr>::value;
    std::cout << std::is_same<int&, intrr>::value;
    std::cout << std::is_same<int&, intr>::value;
}
```

Output: `111`

Thomas Becker's article on [*Rvalue References explained*](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html) provides a nice table:

> 1. A& & becomes A&
> 2. A& && becomes A&
> 3. A&& & becomes A&
> 4. A&& && becomes A&&