# Issues concerning const decltype(x)&

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, language-lawyer, decltype

Consider the following code:

```
int a = 1;
const int& b = a;
std::cout << std::is_same<const decltype(b)&, const int&>();
```

It compiles on clang 3.5 while GCC 4.9 gives the following error:

`error: 'const' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'const int&'`

Which one is correct according to the standard? My guess is that GCC is standard-conformant, just as you can't do `int& const b = a;`.

Comment: Which line does make the error ? The `const int& b = a;` or the next one ?

Comment: FWIW, the cv-qualifiers on a reference are ignored for a *decltype-specifier* in a declaration (see [dcl.ref]).

Comment: `const decltype(b)&` is not the same as `decltype(b)& const` so I don't think your analogy to `int& const` is particularly sound.

Comment: @Aracthor: Why would it be the `const int& b = a` line?

Comment: @Lightning Racis in Obrit: Because the error just says there is a problem with the 'const' of "const int&", and there is a "const in&" on the "const int& b = a" line.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit `decltype(b)` is `const int&`. In `const decltype(b)&`, `const` applies to `decltype(b)`, which leads to `const int& const`. So the analogy should be sound.

Comment: @Aracthor, The error says `const` cannot be applied to `const int &` (because it is a reference). The `const` in the second line applies to `int`.

Comment: @Lingxi: _"In const decltype(b)&, const applies to decltype(b)"_ Right, exactly. It does not apply to the `&`, which is the problem in `int& const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the code is valid and the two types are the same.

[dcl.ref]/1 says:

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a *typedef-name* (7.1.3, 14.1) or *decltype-specifier* (7.1.6.2), in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored.

Since you are introducing the first `const` through a *decltype-specifier*, it is ignored, and your first type is equivalent to `decltype(b)&`.

Now [dcl.ref]/6 says:

> If a *typedef-name* (7.1.3, 14.1) or a *decltype-specifier* (7.1.6.2) denotes a type `TR` that is a reference to a type `T`, an attempt to create the type "lvalue reference to *cv* `TR`" creates the type "lvalue reference to `T`" [...]

Your *decltype-specifier* denotes the type "reference to `const int`", and you are attempting to create an lvalue reference, so you end up with an lvalue reference to `const int`.

Comment: Would these not apply only to declarations, and not template arguments? I don't see why the rules would change, though.

Comment: So, an rvalue reference type `TR` can be overridden, obtaining an lvalue reference.

Comment: @chris I think the cases of templates are governed by other rules dedicated to them.

Comment: @Lingxi, You can check out [reference collapsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2) for those rules.