# Named rvalue references

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Please pardon my lack of clarity on this topic. I am trying to create functions for inserting a big class into a vector. In this example, I use vector of ints as the big class.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> vectorOfVectors;

void fn(const vector<int> &v) {
    vectorOfVectors.push_back(v);

}
void fn(vector<int> &&v) {
    vectorOfVectors.push_back(std::move(v));
}

int main() {
    vector<int> a({1});
    const vector<int> b({2});
    fn(std::move(a));
    fn(b);
    cout<<b[0];
}
```

Obviously, I want no copying to be done when possible. My questions:

1. Does this code do the right thing?
2. Is there a better way of doing this?
3. For the same approach to work with custom classes, do I need to define move constructors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does this code do the right thing?

Yes. C++11 added `std::vector::push_back(T&&)` for this very reason.

> Is there a better way of doing this?

Your `fn(const vector<int> &v)` and `fn(vector<int> &&v)` are both doing the same thing, pushing the argument `v` onto the end of `vectorOfVectors`. In lieu of your two `fn` functions you could have used one function template that uses perfect forwarding.

```
template<typename T>
void fn(T &&v) {
    vectorOfVectors.push_back(std::forward<T>(v));
}
```

How this works is thanks to the C++11 [reference collapsing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2) and `std::forward`. The template type `T` becomes `vector<int>&` in the case that `v` is an lvalue but `vector<int>&&` in the case that `v` is an rvalue. The reference collapsing rules means that `vector<int>& &&` becomes `vector<int>&` while `vector<int>&& &&` becomes `vector<int>&&`. This does exactly what you want, calling the version of `push_back` that does a copy in the case of an lvalue but the version that does a move in the case of an rvalue.

One downside is that this sometimes can lead to interesting diagnostics when you get things wrong. ("Interesting" here means hundreds of lines of inscrutable diagnostic text from either g++ or clang++). Another downside is that templates can result in a case of "converters gone wild".

> For the same approach to work with custom classes, do I need to define move constructors?

Not necessarily. You'll get an implicitly declared move constructor if the class doesn't declare a user-defined destructor, copy constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator. The implicitly declared move constructor will be defined as deleted if the class has non-movable data members or derives from a class that can't be moved or deleted.

To me, that's a bit too much to remember. I don't know if this is a good practice or a bad one, but I've started using `Foo(const Foo&)=default`, with similar declarations for the other rule of five functions. I'll also qualify the constructors as `explicit` in many cases to avoid the "converters gone wild" problem.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the "In some cases yes" part? And how the template works?

Comment: @user2308211 - I changed the "in some cases, yes" to your particular case. Generalizing a bit, you should think of templatizing a function if you have a `f(T&)` and `f(T&&)` that are copy-and-paste identical to one another except for a `std::move` or two in the move version of `f()`.

Comment: "The template type `T` becomes [...] `vector<int>&&` in the case that `v` is an rvalue" - no, in that case `T` is just `vector<int>`. The forwarding reference version also catches everything under the sun (important if you have overloads or need to inspect whether `f(something)` is well-formed). Finally, if the type at issue is cheap to move (like `vector<int>`), a simpler approach is to take the argument by value and then unconditionally move: `void f(vector<int> v) { vectorOfVectors.push_back(std::move(v)); }`.

Answer (score 2):

1. It does avoid copying `a`.
2. Yes. Using `push_back` means you're forced to construct at least two objects while `emplace_back` and perfect forwarding could do less work.

   ```
   template<typename... Ts>
   auto fn(Ts &&...ts)
     -> decltype(vectorOfVectors.emplace_back(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...), void())
   {
       vectorOfVectors.emplace_back(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
   }
   ```

   http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sT65g3sDxHI0ZZhZ

3. As long as you're using `push_back`, you would need the classes to be move constructible in order to avoid copying. You don't necessarily need to define the move contructor yourself though, if you can get the default definition.