# Confusion about the return type of std::get() on std::tuple objects

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, language-lawyer, decltype

Please see the following code (see it live [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fVrjQ0eP3hhBGE19)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct S {
  int&& v;  
};

int main() {
  std::tuple<int&&> t(1);
  std::cout << std::is_same<int, decltype(std::get<0>(t))>{} << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::is_same<int&, decltype(std::get<0>(t))>{} << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::is_same<int&&, decltype(std::get<0>(t))>{} << std::endl;
  S s{1};
  std::cout << std::is_same<int&&, decltype(s.v)>{} << std::endl;
}
```

I'm expecting to see the output `0 0 1 1`, but both GCC and clang give the output `0 1 0 1` instead. Really confused. Could someone give me an explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at signature of `std::get`:

```
template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
constexpr std::tuple_element_t<I, tuple<Types...> >&
    get( tuple<Types...>& t )

template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
constexpr std::tuple_element_t<I, tuple<Types...> >&&
    get( tuple<Types...>&& t )
```

In your case `t` is a l-value, so it return `int&& &` which became `int&`.

Comment: Any ideas why `std::tuple_element<0,std::tuple<int&>>::type&` returns an `int&` How does `int&` + `&` collapses into int&?

Comment: @Phantom: Look at [concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2)

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant `std::get` overloads are these:

```
template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
typename std::tuple_element<I, tuple<Types...> >::type&
get( tuple<Types...>& t );

template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
typename std::tuple_element<I, tuple<Types...> >::type&&
get( tuple<Types...>&& t );
```

Note that an lvalue reference is returned if the argument is an lvalue, and an rvalue reference is returned if the argument is an rvalue. `t` is an lvalue, so an lvalue is returned.