# why not introduce autoval/autoref or decltype_val/decltype_ref to C++?

Tags: c++11, c++14

Since c++11, auto and decltype have been introduced.

They are great features. But it also introduce some headaches.

For example, what is the type of the following expressions?

```
int i = 10, j = 20;
int &ri = i;
auto ai = ri; //what is the type of ai? int or int &

decltype(i);   
decltype((i)); //???
decltype(i+j); //???
```

I am wondering if we can borrow the idea of "override"? Actually there are a lot of questions in stackoverflow asking about what/why is the type of decltype(some expression)

For example：

```
autoref ai = ri;   //we need a reference
decltype_val(i+j); //we need a value
```

If we need a value or reference, we just explicit show our idea to compiler, is it possible?

Comment: If you need a value use `auto`; if you need a reference use `auto&`. What needs to change exactly?

Comment: it is not intuitive. since auto ai=i; we got int, so auto ai=ri; we should got int&, but we actually got int.

Comment: But if `autoref` is always a reference, so is `auto&`. And if `decltype_val` is always a value, so is `auto`. It appears to me that you're asking for existing functionality using new keywords – meh.

Comment: this is not the right forum to discuss proposals to the c++ language. std-proposals google group please. If you have a question or problem about the current c++ language or existing proposals that is objectively answerable, that would be acceptable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it calls for opinions about a language extension.

Comment: You shouldn't vote on this question based on if you agree with the new keywords or not, but based upon if you find the question relevant. For someone not very familiar with `auto` and `decltype` I personally think it's a good question. And I think the good answers it got helped my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`auto` behaves like function template argument deduction : it strips away `const`, `volatile` and references, and uses [reference collapsing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2). Thus :

- `auto i = x` is always a value;
- `auto &i = x` is always a lvalue reference;
- `auto &&i = x` is always either an lvalue or a rvalue reference, depending on `x`.

`decltype` has no deduction or type adjustment whatsoever : it is always the type of its operand, `const` and references and all. It does have the "gotcha" that :

- `decltype(x)` yields the exact type of `x`, whereas
- `decltype((x))` yields the type of the expression `(x)`, which forms a reference to `x`.

Comment: "*`decltype` has no deduction or type adjustment whatsoever*" it does if you give it a parenthesized expression – `decltype(i)` and `decltype((i))` are different in the OP's case.

Comment: @ildjarn I'm not sure whether this is `decltype`'s effect : I think `(x)` is already a reference, even without `decltype`.

Comment: @ildjarn To be fair, it produces the type of a variable passed.  If passed an expression, it instead gives the type of the expression.  It has *two* slightly different behaviors, not "type adjustment or deduction".  The effect of this is that `decltype((x))` is different than `decltype(x)`, because the second is a variable.

Comment: @Yakk : Understood, I just think saying it 'does no type adjustment' is a little unclear bordering misleading given the OP's specific examples.

Comment: @ildjarn You're right, addended for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But with auto and decltype, especially decltype, we have to remember a lot boring rules, isn't good that we can tell the idea from the expression explicitly.

Comment: @camino It's not that much, really. Your `autoref` is exactly `auto&` (or `auto&&` if you want to allow rvalues as well), and your `decltype_val` is pretty similar to plain `auto` when you give it an initializer.

Comment: "it strips away const, volatile and references" - only for plain `auto`.

Comment: @T.C. Yes. then you can add your own "decorations" back onto it.

Comment: @Quentin It's not just you adding back. `const int i = 5; auto& p = i;` is OK and `decltype(p)` is `const int &`.

Answer (score 5):

Auto behaves almost exactly like a deduced type parameter in a template function.

So

```
template<class T>void foo0(T t0);
template<class T>void foo1(T& t1);
template<class T>void foo2(T const& t2);
template<class T>void foo3(T&& t3);
template<class T>void foo4(T const&& t4);

foo#(expression); // pseudo code on this line
```

correspond to:

```
auto t0 = expression;
auto& t1 = expression;
auto const& t2 = expression;
auto&& t3 = expression;
auto const&& t4 = expression;
```

in that the types of the `t#` are nearly identical (there are some slight differences; auto supports `{}` in some cases, for example).

Careful use of `auto` lets you say "a value" or "an lvalue reference" or "a reference I won't modify" or "any reference at all".

`decltype` also has its quirks.  If passed the name of a variable, it returns the type that the variable was declared as.  Otherwise, if passed an expression, it returns the type of the *expression*.

This means `decltype((x))` where `x` is a variable is the type of the expression `(x)`, while `decltype(x)` is the type of the variable `x` (the type it was declared as -- the **decl** *aration* **type**).

In general, you can apply type manipulation helpers to the return value of `decltype`, such as `std::remove_reference_t` or `std::decay_t` to make it not a reference, or suitable for storage.

A reason why new keywords where not added is because every keyword runs the risk of breaking existing code; a keyword cannot be used as a type name or variable name.  `auto` was an obsolete keyword that was repurposed, and for `decltype` they carefully searched available code bases to show it was not used anywhere they could find.  The C++ standard committee seeks to minimize the number of such keywords added, which is one reason why `mutable` and `auto` and `typename` and `template` are used in new contexts rather than new keywords being introduced.

As an aside, `final` and `override` got in by being *positional keywords*, not full keywords.