# Why is adding a reference to a rvalue reference not an error?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, language-lawyer, reference-collapsing

I have the following typedef:

```
using int_ref = int&&;
```

Why does the following code not produce an error (or print `false`)?

```
std::cout << is_same< int_ref, int_ref&& >::value; // prints 1
```

I would expect that `int_ref&&` gets expanded to `int&& &&` which is obviously not possible. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is due to [reference collapsing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2).

Basically, although you can't write a reference to a reference yourself, in some cases (typedefs, template parameters, decltypes) you can add create a reference to a reference type, which collapses as follows:

```
A& & -> A&
A& && -> A&
A&& & -> A&
A&& && -> A&&
```

In your case, `int_ref` is `int&&`, so `int&& &&` becomes `int&&`.

---

The relevant standard quote:

> `(N3337) [dcl.ref]/6:` If a typedef (7.1.3), a type *template-parameter* (14.3.1), or a *decltype-specifier* (7.1.6.2) denotes a type `TR`
>   that is a reference to a type `T`, an attempt to create the type “lvalue reference to *cv* `TR`”creates the type
>   “lvalue reference to `T`” , while an attempt to create the type “rvalue reference to *cv* `TR`”creates the type `TR`.

Comment: Ah, cool! Do you, by any chance, have a reference to the c++ specification where this is mentioned?

Comment: @tobspr Sure, added

Comment: @tobspr If you've ever heard someone talk about "universal references" or "forwarding references", that's the simplified explanation of reference collapsing that many people find more intuitive and useful in practice. You've found one of the few corner cases where it doesn't work.