# rvalue reference in class template vs function template

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue-reference

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class test
{
public:
    test(T&& t)
    {
    }
};

template <typename T>
void succeed(T&& t)
{
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    test<int> t(i);    // failed to compile
    succeed(i);        // OK
    return 0;
}
```

Error from GCC 5.2:
    main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
    main.cpp:20:18: error: cannot bind 'int' lvalue to 'int&&'
         test t(i);
                      ^
    main.cpp:7:5: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'test::test(T&&) [with T = int]'
         test(T&& t)
         ^~~~

Could someone explain why the class template cannot compile but function template is OK?
Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to explain if we actually know the errors you get. When posting question regarding build errors, always include the complete error output in full and unedited, in the body of the question. Please edit your question to include that. Also please include the compiler you are using, and which version of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion is probably rooted in your assumption that in both cases `T` is `int`. This is why you presume that these two cases as similar. In reality they are not.

In the class version you are manually specifying what `T` is. You explicitly tell the compiler that `T` is `int`. Constructor parameter type `T &&` in this case becomes `int &&`, which cannot bind to a regular lvalue. Hence the error.

In the function version you don't tell the compiler what `T` is, but instead you expect the compiler to *deduce* it. In situations like yours the language is deliberately designed to deduce `T` as `int &` (note: not as `int`, but rather as `int &`). Once `T` is deduced as `int &`, the so called ["reference collapsing" rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2) lead to function parameter type `T &&` becoming `int &` - an ordinary lvalue reference. This parameter can successfully bind to lvalue argument `i`.

That explains the difference you observe.

For the sake of experiment, in the latter case you can suppress template argument deduction and specify the template argument explicitly

```
succeed<int>(i);
```

That will forcefully specify `T` as `int` and lead to the very same error as in the class version for the very same reason.

Similarly, you can "simulate" function's behavior for your class by specifying the template argument as `int &`

```
test<int &> t(i);
```

The same "reference collapsing" rules will make your constructor invocation to compile successfully.

Answer (score 5):

In `succeed`, `T&& t` is a *forwarding reference*, not an rvalue reference. But in `test`, it is an rvalue reference.

A forwarding reference happens only when the parameter is `T&&`, and `T` is a template parameter of that function. In your code `T` is a template parameter of the enclosing class, so it doesn't count as a forwarding reference.

A forwarding reference may bind to both lvalues and rvalues.

During the drafting of C++11 it was suggested to use different syntax for forwarding references than rvalue references (instead of using `T&& t` for both); however the committee eventually settled on the current behaviour.

For a more detailed description of template parameter deduction, including a more precise specification of when `T&&` becomes a forwarding reference, [see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) -- search for the term "forwarding reference" to find the special rules for forwarding references.