# Variadic template as parameters to std::function

Tags: c++, function, c++11, variadic-templates

I want to build a structure that allow me to call member functions with an undefined number of parameters. For now I wrote something like this

```
template<typename Class, typename Return, typename ... Args>
struct Caller
{
private:
    std::function<Return(Args ...)> callerFunction;

    Caller() = delete;
    Caller(const Caller&) = delete;
    Caller(Caller&&) = delete;
    Caller& operator=(const Caller&) = delete;

public:
    ~Caller() = default;

    Caller(Class& instance, Return(Class::*function)(Args ...))
    {
        callerFunction = [&instance, function](Args... args)
        {
            return (instance.*function)(args ...);
        };
    }

    Return operator() (Args ... args)
    {
        return callerFunction(args ...);
    }
};
```

I am afraid that I cannot work around the fact that I cannot declare a std::function variable as `std::function<Return<Args&& ...)> callerFunction`

When I try to do this the compiler says that it cannot convert from `int` to `int&&` (if for example the parameters are `int`s), so I'm guessing that the function sees the `Args&& ...` as a parameter pack of rvalue references. Am I correct?

Is there a workaround?

**Edit:** Ok, I was declaring the function inside the Caller constructor in the wrong way.

Wrong way --> `Caller(Class& instance, Return(Class::*function)(Args&& ...))`

Right way --> `Caller(Class& instance, Return(Class::*function)(Args ...))`

The (I guess) right implementation is

```
template<typename Class, typename Return, typename ... Args>
struct Caller
{
private:
    std::function<Return(Args&& ...)> callerFunction;

    Caller() = delete;
    Caller(const Caller&) = delete;
    Caller(Caller&&) = delete;
    Caller& operator=(const Caller&) = delete;

public:
    ~Caller() = default;

    Caller(Class& instance, Return(Class::*function)(Args ...))
    {
        callerFunction = [&instance, function] (Args&&... args)
        {
            return (instance.*function)(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
        };
    }

    Return operator() (Args&& ... args)
    {
        return callerFunction(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
    }
};
```

Now the question is: Why do I need to declare the function anyway without the double &?

Comment: What compiler do you use? It works in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: And show us how you create an instance of a caller.

Comment: I'm on Visual Studio 2013 and I do something like this `Caller<A, bool, int, int, int> caller(a, &A::foo);`. Anyway, I would change the structure by using `std::forward` when necessary.

Comment: I'm trying on VS2017 and I have the same issue. The full code I'm using is here https://pastebin.com/99QFwfA8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your class template like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
 A(T&& param)
}
```

And then create an instace:

```
A<int> myInstance(someIntVariable);
```

**It won't compile**. The reason is, the type of `T` is explicitly specified by you (as an `int`, in `A<int>`), and your class constructor parameter is no longer `T&&`, but `int&&`, so it's no longer universal reference (which accepts both lvalue and rvalue references), but regular rvalue reference.

Next, if you pass it some integer, there is a type missmatch error because you pass a regular variable when rvalue reference is expected.

In your example you explicitly defined function signatures, so the same applies - constructor expects a function taking rvalue references to Args..., but that's not true.

**I think it's better explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785755/rvalue-reference-in-class-template-vs-function-template)**

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it is so obvious now! My only doubt is: I DON'T need to use forward in any case because I'm specifying the types of every variable that I will pass to the function, right? I don't need to use forward even in the operator() function, that I use to call the member function with the arguments, right?

Comment: @Astinog That's right. std::forward should be used only with universal references. It's sole purpose is to pass the parameter (forward) to another function without altering it's type, so if the T&& will be passed a lvalue, the lvalue will be passed, if rvalue then rvalue. You can read more about it if you google the "perfect forwarding in C++", there are lot's of resources on the subject :)

Answer (score 0):

`int&&` is not the same as `int`.  If your method takes an `int`, it doesn't take an `int&&`.  They are different types.

There is no conversion between different signatures of member function pointer.

Forwarding references aren't magic.  They depend on deduction rules (and no use of `Args&&...` above is in a deduced context) and on reference collapsing rules.

As such, your

```
Return operator() (Args&& ... args)
```

is also wrong.  If `Args...` is `int`, then you won't be able to call the above with `int a; blah.operator()(a)` as `a` won't bind to `int&&`.

Honestly, your entire type should be thrown out and replaced with a `std::function<Return(Args...)>`.  `Class` is a useless narrowing of what the function does, and your wrappers don't add much either.

Users can just `[&a](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){ return a.foo(decltype(args)(args)...); }` if they really need to replicate your constructor, or use `std::bind( &A::foo, std::ref(a) )`