# Is it specified in the C++11 standard that std::begin(Container&&) returns const_iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11

Here's a link to relevant code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  auto iter = begin(std::move(v));
  if(std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*iter)>::type>::value)
    std::cout<<"is const\n";
  return 0;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/253c6373befe8e50

I ran into this behavior because of a `declval<Container>()` in a `decltype` expression with `std::begin`. Both gcc and clang return iterators which yield const references when dereferenced. It probably makes sense since r-value references usually bind to expiring objects that you don't want to mutate. However, I could not find any documentation on this to determine whether it's mandated by the standard. I couldn't find any relevant overloads of `begin()` or ref-qualified overloads of `Container::begin()`.

Update: The answers clarified what's happening but the interactions can be subtle as demonstrated below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
  if(std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*begin(std::declval<std::vector<std::string>>()))>::type>::value)
    std::cout<<"(a) is const\n";
  if(!std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::declval<std::vector<std::string>>().begin())>::type>::value)
    std::cout<<"(b) is not const\n";
  if(!std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*begin(std::declval<std::vector<std::string>&>()))>::type>::value)
    std::cout<<"(c) is not const\n";
  return 0;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15c17b288f8d69bd

Naively, you wouldn't expect different results for (a) and (b) when ::begin is just defined in terms of calling vector::begin. However the absence of std::begin overloads that take non-const r-value reference and return iterator (or ref-qualified vector::begin overloads which return const_iterator) cause exactly that to happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's try to analyze what happens, step by step:

1. You're calling `std::begin(std::vector<int>&&)`, but `std::begin` [has no overload that takes an rvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin):

   ```
   template< class C > 
   auto begin( C& c ) -> decltype(c.begin());

   template< class C > 
   auto begin( const C& c ) -> decltype(c.begin());
   ```

---

2. Due to [reference collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2), a temporary *(xvalue)* will only bind to a `const` lvalue reference:

   > If you call Fwd with an xvalue, we again get Type&& as the type of v. This will not allow you to call a function that takes a non-const lvalue, as an xvalue cannot bind to a non-const lvalue reference. It can bind to a const lvalue reference, so if Call used a const&, we could call Fwd with an xvalue.

   *(From the linked answer)*.

---

3. Therefore, the

   ```
    template<class C> auto begin(const C& c) -> decltype(c.begin());
   ```

   overload is being called, which returns a `const` iterator.

   *Why?*

   Because `std::begin(v)` calls `v.begin()`, [which returns a `const_iterator` when called on `const` instances of `std::vector`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin)

Answer (score 8):

As you can see in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin the interesting overloads are:

```
template<class C> auto begin(C& c) -> decltype(c.begin());
template<class C> auto begin(const C& c) -> decltype(c.begin());
```

and `std::vector<int>&&` can only bind to the second overload (so returns `const_iterator`).

Comment: That makes sense but it's a bit surprising that `decltype(*begin(declval<std::vector<std::string>>()))` is a const std::string& when neither the vector nor string is const. If vector::begin were used instead the result would be string&! With ::begin you'd need to pass vector& to declval to avoid getting const string&. [This link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15c17b288f8d69bd) illustrates the subtlety.

Comment: That should have been std::begin instead of ::begin above.