# Using std::forward with a forwarding reference

Tags: c++, templates, forwarding

Is this function

```
template< typename T >
void foo( T&& in )
{
  bar( std::forward<T>( in ) );
}
```

equivalent to

```
template< typename T >
void foo( T&& in )
{
  bar( std::forward<T&&>( in ) );
}
```

where a forwarding reference `T&&` is passed to `std::forward`?

Comment: Empirical test: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mJ0gobWkiplIRGMJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are equivalent, but the idiomatic way is to use plain `T`.

Here are how the `forward` functions templates are defined in C++14:

```
1)
template< class T >
constexpr T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t ) noexcept;
2)
template< class T >
constexpr T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t ) noexcept;
```

First, let's modify your example a bit to make the types less confusing:

```
template< typename U >
void foo( U&& in )
{
    using T = U; // or U&&
    bar( std::forward<T>( in ) );
}
```

Now, let's consider the return type of `forward` - `T&&`, `int` used as example:

```
 |     U |     T |              T&& |
 | int   | int   |            int&& |
 | int&  | int&  | int&  && = int&  |
 | int&& | int&& | int&& && = int&& |
```

and with `using T = U&&`

```
 |     U |     U&& (also T) |              T&& |
 | int   |            int&& | int&& && = int&& |
 | int&  | int&  && = int&  | int&  && = int&  |
 | int&& | int&& && = int&& | int&& && = int&& |
```

So, the result types are the same.

As for the parameters, `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type` is a dead giveaway. I'm using `remove_ref<T>` for readability:

```
 |     T | remove_ref<T> |    remove_ref<T>& | remove_ref<T>&& |
 | int   |           int |              int& |           int&& |
 | int&  |           int |              int& |           int&& |
 | int&& |           int |              int& |           int&& |
```

As you can see, this isn't dependant on the reference-ness of the template parameter at all.

Reference collapsing is explained more in-depth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2).