# What does const_forward do in optional implementation in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Hi I am looking at one of `std::optional` implementations here at [here](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/blob/master/optional.hpp) and I have found this code snippet confuses me:

```
// workaround: std utility functions aren't constexpr yet
template <class T> inline constexpr T&& constexpr_forward(typename 
std::remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

So I don't understand this in the following way:

1. What does `typename` do here? Just to declare the following part is a type?
2. Why do we need `std::remove_reference` here? Didn't we add the reference back in the `type&` part?
3. What does "std utility functions are not constexpr yet" mean? How does this function make them constexpr? The body of it is just a `static_cast`.
4. This function is used in a number of constructors and it looks like this: `template <class... Args>
   constexpr storage_t( Args&&... args ) : value_(constexpr_forward<Args>(args)...) {}`, so what does it do here to args?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It may be more productive to ask one clear question at a time (after searching SO for duplicates.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <class T> inline constexpr T&& constexpr_forward(typename 
std::remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

> 1. What does `typename` do here? Just to declare the following part is a type?

`std::remove_reference<T>::type` is a *dependent type* which depends on the template parameter `T`, hence we need `typename` to tell the compiler we are trying to use a [*dependent-name*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name),

> 2. Why do we need `std::remove_reference` here? Didn't we add the reference back in the `type&` part?

If you check the example usage of this utility function as in [here](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/blob/master/optional.hpp#L331)

```
....
template <class... Args> explicit constexpr constexpr_optional_base(in_place_t, Args&&... args)
      : init_(true), storage_(constexpr_forward<Args>(args)...) {}
...
```

You can see, a variadic fowarding reference type is used as the explicit template argument to `constexpr_foward<Args>(args)...`. This will preserve the [value category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) of the type. When any of the argument is a reference, it will be as if we called that utility function with `constexpr_forward<Arg01&>(arg01)`. And the instatiation of that template will be

```
inline constexpr Arg01&&& constexpr_forward(Arg01& t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<Arg01&&&>(t);
}
```

and by [reference collapsing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2), we have

```
inline constexpr Arg01& constexpr_forward(Arg01& t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<Arg01&>(t);
}
```

Actually, the remove reference *should* be superfluous there (read about reference collapsing);

> 3. What does "std utility functions are not constexpr yet" mean? How does this function make them constexpr? The body of it is just a `static_cast`.

It does nothing more than [forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward) a non-`constexpr` function in `constexpr` functions and constructor.

> 4. This function is used in a number of constructors and it looks like this: `template <class... Args>
>      constexpr storage_t( Args&&... args ) : value_(constexpr_forward<Args>(args)...) {}`, so what does it do here to args?

Basically as explained above..

Answer (score 2):

You may have to go back a step and do some more reading, this code is reasonably advanced and your questions indicate that you haven't read up on some of this stuff. I would recommend Modern Effective C++, by Scott Meyers. As to your specific questions:

1. Yes, it is necessary to use `typename`, because we're dealing with a member of a template class, which is a dependent type. Think of it as assuring the compiler that this thing is really a type, at a point before the compiler can verify it (because the template hasn't been instantiated, only defined, so it doesn't know what `T` is).
2. Unlike most template functions, the idea with `std::forward` is to explicitly specify the template parameter to make it work correctly. This form disables type deduction which is desirable in this context (rare). Notice that removing a reference and adding it back isn't the same as doing nothing, as if it's not a reference to start with, it still ends up as one. That's the goal; to always take an lvalue reference.
3. It simply means they are not marked `constexpr`. A function can be used in constant expressions, if it is marked `constexpr`. Not all functions can be marked `constexpr`, there are restrictions. The standard library function `std::forward` can be constexpr, but simply isn't. This function is just a workaround for that.
4. This is basically equivalent to `std::forward`, so it would be good to google about that and read about it, as it's not a trivial thing to grok (and the book I mentioned talks about it). Basically the idea is that once you have a function accepting a set of arguments, suppose it wants to forward those arguments elsewhere. The thing is that all symbol names (in this case, `args`) are considered lvalues (even though they are rvalue references... as I said, it's confusing, type vs value category). However, if the user passed in any temporaries then we want it to be forwarded correctly (i.e. as a temporary) to the next function. `std::forward` ensures that things passed in as rvalues, get cast back into rvalue references and can be used correctly by the inner function.

I hope that helps. Again, you will need to spend some time reading to gain a deeper understanding of value categories, and rvalue references to fully  digest it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually have that book but did not have time to read it before.