# How can we instantiate template functions with a reference type?

Tags: c++, c++11

C++ does not instantiate templates with, say `T = Hoge&`.

A minimal example:

- `hoge.h`:

  ```
  #include<cstdio>
  class Hoge
  {
    public:
      Hoge()
        : hoge(0)
      {
      }
      ~Hoge()
      {
      }

      int hoge;
      void print() { printf("%d\n", hoge); }
  };

  template<typename T>
  void f(T a);
  ```
- `hoge.cpp`:

  ```
  #include "hoge.h"
  template<typename T>
  void f(T a)
  {
    a.print();
  }

  template void f<Hoge &>(Hoge &a);
  ```
- `main.cpp`:

  ```
  #include "hoge.h"
  int main(void)
  {
    Hoge h;
    f(h);
    return 0;
  }
  ```

I compiled these with: `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp hoge.cpp`. But it gives a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "void f<Hoge>(Hoge)", referenced from:
      _main in aa-e35088.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Next, I changed `f(h)` in  `main.cpp` to `f<Hoge &>`, and the error disappeared.

Why is `f<Hoge &>(Hoge &)` not called in the first case?
For this case, I can avoid errors by typing `f<Hoge &>` every time. But, when it comes to overloaded operators, it cannot be done.

Please tell me how to solve this error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The compiler will try to deduce the simplest template `T` possible. Here, `T=Hoge` is fine, so the compiler doesn't try more elaborated forms.

You can clearly state your intent though. Try the following:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T& a);
```

`T` will still be deduced as `Hoge`, but your function `f` will get a reference.
This allows the reader to clearly see that directly in `f` prototype.

When it comes to template argument deduction, there is a lot of rules occurring under the compiler hood. When I state the compiler deduce the simplest T possible, I'm really cutting corners. Here is a fiable source: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)

Answer (score 5):

You can *instantiate* the function with a reference type just the way you did. However, the compiler will **not** *deduce* the template argument as a reference type. You can verify that you can instantiate the function template OK by not having the compiler deduce the argument but rather specifying the argument:

```
f<Hoge&>(h);
```

If you want to get a reference type *deduced* you'll need to use a *forwarding reference* as an argument of your function template:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&& a);
```

When using a forwarding reference as a template argument and passing an `Hoge` argument, the argument is deduced according to the value category of argument:

```
Hoge       h;
Hoge const c;

f(h);       // T becomes Hoge&
f(c);       // T becomes Hoge const&
f(Hoge());  // T becomes Hoge
```

Comment: @DietmarKühl I'm sure you mean "will *not* deduce the template argument as a reference type" (unless a forwarding reference is used).

Comment: @M.M Actually, `T` becomes `Hoge` in this case as well. It's the same as in `f(Hoge())`. Note that `T` is the name of the template parameter and not the type of the function parameter (`T &&`).

Comment: @ArneVogel OK. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13726754/1505939) claimed `T&&` deduced for xvalue argument, but maybe it is wrong