# Wrapper for perfect forwarding constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, wrapper, perfect-forwarding

I want to make a wrapper for a constructor of a class B.

Since some part of the class B is replaceable, I group each implementation of those parts into several class A.

I use perfect forwarding to provide a default implementation of A for constructing a B.

The problem is the wrapper doesn't work. How to fix this?

Thanks.

The following is also at https://godbolt.org/g/AWwtbf

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    A() { _x = 2; }
    int _x;
};

template<typename T, typename C=A<T> >
class B {
public:
    explicit B(T x, C&& a = A<T>())
            : _x(x), _a(a) {
    }
    T _x;
    A<T>& _a;
};

template<typename T, typename C=A<T> >
B<T, A<T>> make_b(T x, C&& c = A<T>()) {
    return B<int, A<int>>(x, c);
};

int main() {
    B<int, A<int>> b1(1);  // this works.
    auto b2 = make_b(1);  // this doesn't
}
```

Error:

```
error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'A<int>&&' to lvalue of type 'A<int>'

     return B<int, A<int>>(x, c);
```

Comment: Read [this](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html). You seem to have some fundamental misunderstandings

Comment: After reading pages 1 and 2, I think that `A<T>()` is a rvalue. It represents calling the constructor of `A` instead of the actual result, which is an instance of `A`. If `A` has a move constructor that takes in this rvalue and create the actual instance of `A`, and change type of `B::_a` to `A<T>` instead of `A<T>&`, it would be fine?

Comment: That sounds too complicated. B and A would be created at the same time. I will just ask B to have an A as an attribute. And maybe also make `B::_a` public. That way, creating a B would also create a A, but I have the flexibility to choose what kind of A is created.

Comment: You should continue reading, it will be worth it if you are planning to do anything serious with C++. Every expression has a value category, it is either lvalue or rvalue. `A<T>()` is indeed a rvalue (its value category) and is also an `A<T>` (its type). This is the _basis_ of perfect forwarding, but is only half the story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to perfect-forward stuff?**

1. Make the type of the argument a `template` parameter.
2. Accept the argument by rvalue-reference (`&&`).
3. `std::forward` the argument.

You got nr. 1 and 2 but forgot nr. 3:

```
template<typename T, typename C=A<T> >
B<T, A<T>> make_b(T x, C&& c = A<T>()) {
    return B<T, A<int>>(x, std::forward<C>(c));
};
```

**How to avoid a dangling reference?**

This code creates a dangling reference, i.e. a reference to an object that's already [gone](http://rextester.com/MJJRFA8436):

```
    explicit B(T x, C&& a = A<T>())
            : _x(x), _a(a) {
    }
    T _x;
    A<T>& _a;
```

Consider what happens here: a temporary `A` is created, the rvalue reference `a` is being used in an lvalue expression (`a`) so it turns into an lvalue reference and `A& _a` subsequently happily binds to it. By the time the full-expression is finished (at the first `;`) the temporary `A` instance is destroyed and `A& _a` refers to a non-existent object. If `_a` is used after that point, the behavior is undefined.

Avoid references as data members until you understand [value categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues), [object lifetime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) and [reference collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2) rules.

Just store `A` by value:

```
    explicit B(T x, C&& a = A<T>())
            : _x(x), _a(std::move(a)) {
    }
    T _x;
    A<T> _a;
```

Or instantiate `A` outside `B` and pass it as an lvalue reference:

```
    explicit B(T x, C& a) : _x(x), _a(a) {}
    C& _a;
```