# Why can an lvalue be passed into a constructor taking a const ref rvalue?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct Square
{
    Square()
    {
        str = new char[10];
        strcpy(str, "Hello");
    }

    ~Square()
    {
        delete str;   
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << "str = '" << str << "'" << endl;
    }

    char * str;    
};

class foo
{
public:
    typedef const Square & sqcref;
    typedef Square & sqref;
    foo(sqref && _ref)
    {
        fooStr = _ref.str;
        _ref.str = 0;
    }

    char * fooStr;
};

int main()
{
    Square s;
    s.print();
    foo f(s);
    s.print();
}
```

Output:

> str = 'Hello'
>   str = '

Inside the constructor for `foo`, it expects an rvalue to a `Square &`, but what is passed in is a `Square &` lvalue. Why does this work?

Comment: Are you sure the 2nd output is '? did you miss a '?

Comment: Strangely, that's what was output. Copy and paste this to http://cpp.sh/ c++14 version to repro.

Comment: I think assigning a && reference like you did does not gurantee the validity of the original object. But more importantly what did you expect would happen? the output seems to match the code.

Comment: i just saw you used a char*. A 0 terminates it that might have thrown a monkey wrench into the output. Try what happens with other values.

Comment: I expect a compiler warning that there is no matching constructor, and in the closest candidate an lvalue can be assigned to an rvalue reference.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2

Comment: Yes, if I cast it do `int *` before output, it outputs as you would expect. None of this is in any way related to the question though, so I don't know why it's important...

Comment: The title is about `const` but the `const` typedef (`sqcref`) is not used. Is that a typo? (But then it wouldn't compile due to the assignment.) Is the `const` relevant or are you just asking about rvalue-lvalue reference collapsing as answered by @mpark?

Comment: @Gladaed, the reason the second `'` is not printed is that the program tries to print a `null` pointer (assigned in the foo constructor) as a C string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to [reference collapsing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference). `sqref&&` where `sqref` is `T&` collapses to `T&`.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/eWeYLdI3l0vSpNvo

Answer (score 8):

It works due to [reference collapsing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) rules in C++11.
Simply put, one cannot create reference to reference to value. So the 'references to references' collapse following below rules

> Val && && -> Val &&
>
> Val & && -> Val &
>
> Val & & -> Val &
>
> Val && & -> Val &

So in Your situation `sqref &&` (which is `Square & &&`) collapses to `Square &`. So this is normal lvalue reference.

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense. mpark beat you to the answer by 1 minute though - thanks all the same :)