# What is the type of a reference of a reference in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, reference-type, reference-collapsing

In the code below, what are the types of a and b?

```
template <class T = const int&>
struct A
{
    T& a;
    T b;
};

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    A<> a{i, i};
    return 1;
}
```

I used the code from this post that can give the type of a variable. -> [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c)

But, it says both types are `i const&`.

```
int main() {
    int i = 1;
    A<> a{i, i};

    std::cout << type_name<decltype(a.a)>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << type_name<decltype(a.b)>() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Are `T&` and `T` be the same type in the above case?

Do those ampersands combine and become r-value or some other rule?

Comment: May be a dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2

Comment: Agree. This might not be the best dup, but it explains the reference collapsing rules. TL;DR: Ampersands do combine, but they form a lvalue-reference, not rvalue one.

Comment: Personally I think that's better as a cross-reference than a dupe but whatever :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is `const int&` because that's what you told it to be.

`T&` is also `const int&` because *reference collapsing* transforms your `T&` into `T`:

> [`[dcl.ref]/6:`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#6) If a *typedef-name* ([dcl.typedef], [temp.param]) or a *decltype-specifier* ([dcl.type.simple]) denotes a type `TR` that is a reference to a type `T`, an attempt to create the type “lvalue reference to *cv* `TR`” creates the type “lvalue reference to `T`”, while an attempt to create the type “rvalue reference to *cv* `TR`” creates the type `TR`. *[ Note:* This rule is known as reference collapsing. *— end note ]*  *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> int i;
> typedef int& LRI;
> typedef int&& RRI;
>
> LRI& r1 = i;                    // r1 has the type int&
> const LRI& r2 = i;              // r2 has the type int&
> const LRI&& r3 = i;             // r3 has the type int&
>
> RRI& r4 = i;                    // r4 has the type int&
> RRI&& r5 = 5;                   // r5 has the type int&&
>
> decltype(r2)& r6 = i;           // r6 has the type int&
> decltype(r2)&& r7 = i;          // r7 has the type int&
> ```
>
> *— end example ]*

This is for convenience, because there is no such thing as `const int& &` (reference to reference; not to be confused with rvalue reference type `const int&&` which does exist!) and it's handy to be able to just write code like yours without having to manually "get rid of" the "extra" `&`.

The rationale behind this rule is explained in more detail here:

- [Concise explanation of reference collapsing rules requested: (1) A& & -> A& , (2) A& && -> A& , (3) A&& & -> A& , and (4) A&& && -> A&&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2)