# Why doesn't C++ standard distinguish rvalue references and forwarding references?

Tags: c++, templates, forwarding-reference, value-categories

As far as I'm aware C++ standard does't distinguish between rvalue references and forwarding references.

I'd like to know the reason behind that.

If I want to write a template function that only accepts lvalue expressions I do the following:

```
template<typename T>
void func(T& param);
```

But if I want to write a template function that only accepts rvalue expressions:

```
template<typename T>
void func(T&& param);
```

it turns out that this function also accepts lvalue expressions.

So the question is: what is the logic behind this language design?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [Concise explanation of reference collapsing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2).

Answer (score 0):

It's also referred to as a universal reference.

As the name implies, it's a universal reference, allowing a lot of different types.

If you want it to stay an r-value ref (T&&), you use, `std:forward<T>(param)`, otherwise you make sure it's the type you want it to be when you pass it to wherever you use it.

Comment: Do note that it used to be called a universal reference.  The proper term now is forwarding

Comment: Universal reference is really an obsolete term.