# Role of std::forward

Tags: c++

Following is the code brought from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward).

```
// [I]
void overloaded_function(const std::string& param) {
    std::cout << "const std::string& version: " << param << '\n';
}

// [II]
void overloaded_function(std::string&& param) {
    std::cout << "std::string&& version: " << param << '\n';
}

template <typename T>
void pass_through_f(T&& param) {
    overloaded_function(std::forward<T>(param));
}

template <typename T>
void pass_through(T&& param) {
    overloaded_function(param);
}

int main() {
    std::string str = "Hello World";

    pass_through_f(str);            // (1)
    pass_through_f(std::move(str)); // (2)

    std::cout << "----------\n";

    pass_through(str);              // (3)
    pass_through(std::move(str));   // (4)

    return 0;
}
```

```
const std::string& version: Hello World
std::string&& version: Hello World
----------
const std::string& version: Hello World
const std::string& version: Hello World
```

When I use `pass_through_f()`, the result between `(1)` and `(2)` is different but they are same when `pass_though()` is called.

My question is, how is the result of `(4)` same with `(3)`? Here's type inferencing process that I thought:

1. In `(4)`, return value of some function is r-value, so `T` of `pass_through()` is inferred as a type same with passed argument. Thus `T` is `std::string&&`.
2. `std::string&&` is r-value reference, and r-value reference is r-value so it calls `overloaded_function() [II]`. Thus its result is same with when `std::forward` is used.

But result is different with my thought. I think I'm misunderstanding something about the way `std::forward` works.

Comment: `void overloaded_function(std::string&& param)` - here `param` has a name, so it's a lvalue. Without `std::move` or `std::forward` to cast it back to a rvalue ref, it will remain lvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in

```
template <typename T>
void pass_through(T&& param) {
    overloaded_function(param);
}
```

`param` is a named variable.  Since it has a name, it is an lvalue, even though it is a reference to an rvalue.  Since it is an lvalue, you call the lvalue function.

You need `std::forward` to "re-cast" it back into a rvalue if it came in as an rvalue.

---

Also note that `T` is not `string&&`.  Since you passed a `string&&`, `T&&` deduces `T` to `string` and the `&&` is kept to make it an rvalue reference.

Comment: A mention of [reference collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2) (not the best link, but all I could find in a minute) might also be in order.