# What is checked in this template exactly?

Tags: c++, templates

I was working a little on this code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename T2>
constexpr bool Assignable = std::is_assignable<T&,T2>::value;

template<typename T>
void test() {
    static_assert(Assignable<T, std::string>, "hello1");
    static_assert(Assignable<T&, std::string>, "hello2");
}

int main()
{
    test<int>();
}
```

I wonder what `static_assert(Assignable<T&, std::string>, "hello2");` checks exactly?

Since `Assignable` already uses `T&` inside, calling `static_assert(Assignable<T, std::string>, "hello1");` should check if reference to type `T` is assignable with `std::string`. I wonder what `T&` inside `static_assert(Assignable<T&, std::string>, "hello2");` does?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [reference collapsing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2), this:

```
static_assert(Assignable<T&, std::string>, "hello2");
```

is logicaly equivalent to code like this one:

```
static_assert(Assignable<T, std::string>, "hello2");
```

Why? Long story short - lvalue reference to lvalue reference collapses to lvalue reference.

Comment: thanks. I knew this condition happens sometimes, but I didn't know exactly when. But as a side question, is there any benefit to keep `&` inside `static_assert(Assignable<T&, std::string>, "hello2");`?

Comment: I don't think so, I believe that with this definition of `Assignable` trait, the second check can and should be removed