# Why does auto&& var2 not imply rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, rvalue-reference, forwarding-reference

Why does `auto&& var2` not mean rvalue reference in the code below?

I would be grateful to have some help with this question.

```
Widget&& var1 = someWidget;      // here, “&&” means rvalue reference
auto&& var2 = var1;              // here, “&&” does not mean rvalue reference
```

Given that `Widget&& var1` is an *rvalue reference*, why isn't it an *rvalue*?

Why does `auto&& var2 = var1;` not mean rvalue reference?

Comment: `auto&& var2 = var1;` means an lvalue reference to an lvalue.  `auto&& var2 = std::move(var1);` means an lvalue reference to an rvalue.  `var2` is itself an lvalue.  `std::move(var2)` is a cast to treat the lvalue as an rvalue.

Comment: Could you explain it more in detial?Why `var1` is a lvalue?

Comment: `var1` is an lvalue because it _named_.  Things that are _named_ are lvalues.

Comment: @Eljay & 眠りネロク  I agree with you that a lvalue is the one which is 
 named.While i think `Widget&& var1` indcates `var1` is a right reference to `someWidget`.I think they are both right.So i am confused.

Comment: `var1` is an lvalue.  `someWidget` is an lvalue.  `var2` is an lvalue.  Things with _names_ are lvalues.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.I agree with your last comment.Then why coment for the code says "&& means rvalue reference"(for more details, see https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)?

Comment: @sunshilong369 **rvalue** and **rvalue reference** are different things. The former is a kind of *value category*. The latter is a kind of *reference* that can only be initialized with an *rvalue* object (an object whose *value category* is *rvalue*).

Comment: As an example with your code: `var1` declared as `Widget&& var1` is a *reference* to `Widget`, specifically an **rvalue reference** to `Widget` – This is the **type** of `var1`. However, when using `var1` in an expression (without marking it with `std::move`), then `var1` is an **lvalue** because it has a name – This the **value category** of `var1`.

Comment: I think i understand your last comment in some degree.But i know i don't completly understand it. I agree with that I am mixing up the type of a reference and its value category indeed.Could you suggest some documentation for me to study?I want to dig deep.I would go out my way to understand it(to separate them).Thank you for your help .

Comment: Maybe this explanation will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues

Comment: @眠りネロク If i understand your last reply(the edited answer) correctly,  since the `var2` is the type of `auto&&`, the real type of `var2` should be deduced by the right part of the expression(with your help, i could understand it now. Thank you.).Meanwhile, "Widget&&" is **always** the type of rvalue reference.I wonder that  whether `auto&&` is a term or not, though i understand that the keyword `auto` indicates that the type should be duduced.

Comment: @sunshilong369 Well, the term for `auto&&` is **universal reference** or **forwarding reference**. A *universal reference* will become an *lvalue reference* or an *rvalue reference* depending on whether it is initialized with an *lvalue* or *rvalue*, respectively. Note that the difference with an ordinary reference is that type deduction occurs (i.e., the `auto`) and a *universal reference* always results in a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given that `Widget&& var1` is an *rvalue reference*, why isn't it an *rvalue*?

`someWidget`, `var1`, and `var2` all have a name and, therefore, they are all *lvalues* regardless of their declared type.

The term *rvalue reference* is about the **type of the reference**, `var1`, whereas the term *rvalue* is about the **value category** of the expression `var1`:

- `var1` declared as `Widget&& var1` is a *reference* to `Widget`, specifically an *rvalue reference* to `Widget` (i.e., `Widget&&`) – This is the **type** of `var1`, which is a reference. The reference type tells you how the reference can be initialized: an *rvalue reference* can only be initialized with an *rvalue*, whereas a non-`const` *lvalue reference* can only be initialized with an *lvalue*.
- When using `var1` in an expression (without marking it with `std::move`), then `var1` is an *lvalue* because it has a name – This the **value category** of `var1`, which is a property of the expression `var1` orthogonal to its type.

Note also that the following statement doesn't compile:

```
Widget&& var1 = someWidget;
```

This compilation error is because `var1` is an *rvalue reference* and, therefore, can only be initialized with an *rvalue*. However, `someWidget` is an *lvalue* since it has a name, and it isn't marked with `std::move` for moving. For the statement to compile you could have done one of the following:

- Declaring `v1` as an *lvalue reference* instead:

  ```
  Widget& var1 = someWidget;
  ```

  The *lvalue reference* `var1` can be initialized with `someWidget`, an *lvalue*.
- Marking `someWidget` for moving with `std::move()`:

  ```
  Widget&& var1 = std::move(someWidget);
  ```

  The *rvalue reference* `var1` can be initialized with `std::move(someWidget)`, an *rvalue*.

---

> Why does `auto&& var2` not mean rvalue reference?

`var2` is a *universal reference* because there is type deduction involved. As such, `var2` will become either an lvalue reference or rvalue reference depending on how it is initialized (`var2` will always be a reference).

The `auto` in `auto&& var2 = var1;` deduces to `Widget&` because `var1` is an lvalue (i.e., `var1` is a named object and you haven't applied `std::move()` to it). Then, `Widget& &&` results in `Widget&` due to [*reference collapsing*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13725747/8012646). To sum up, the statement:

```
auto&& var2 = var1;
```

after type deduction becomes:

```
Widget& var2 = var1;
```

So `var2` is actually an lvalue reference.

---

If you want `var2` to be an rvalue reference, you can apply `std::move()` to the initializing object:

```
auto&& var2 = std::move(var1);
```

after type deduction, this results in:

```
Widget&& var2 = var1;
```

`var2` is an rvalue reference in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Yes, `var1` has a name indeed. `someWidget` has a name too, `someWidget` is a name for an object.So `someWidget` is a lvalue. Since there is a `&&` in `Widget&& var1`, i think `var1` is a rvalue reference to `someWidget`.Where am  i wrong?

Comment: @sunshilong369 There is no contradiction because *type* and *value category* are different properties: `someWidget` is an *lvalue*. Its type, however, is `Widget&&`, i.e., an *rvalue reference*.

Comment: I think you are mixing up the *type* of a reference and its *value category*. `someWidget`, `var1`, and `var2` all have a name and, therefore, they are all *lvalues* (their value category). The *value category* tells you what you can do with these objects. For example, you can't directly use this objects to initialize an *rvalue reference*, whereas you can use them to initialize an *lvalue reference*. Whether a reference is of **type** *lvalue* or *rvalue*, tells you how it can be initialized. For example, you can initialize an rvalue reference with a temporary, but not an lvalue reference.

Comment: @sunshilong369 I've edited your question to include the original one as well as your follow-up question. I've also extended my answer accordingly. I hope it helps.

Comment: I think i mostly understand it.Thank you for your generous help.