# Using std::enable_if with constexpr argument for overload resolution doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, enable-if

I'm trying to add function overload for a function template based on the type of one of the template parameters and passing an argument defined as consexpr somewhere else to aid in overload resolution.

Here's a code sample for what I'm trying to achieve:

```
struct use_my_impl_t {};
constexpr use_my_impl_t use_my_impl;

template<
        typename T,
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, use_my_impl_t>::value>::type * = nullptr>
void foo(int i, T&& t)
{
    std::cout << "Using my impl: " << --i << std::endl;
}

template<
    typename T,
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, use_my_impl_t>::value>::type * = nullptr>
    void foo(int i, T&& t)
{
    std::cout << "Using default impl: " << ++i << std::endl;
}
```

So when I pass an instance of `use_my_impl_t` as a second argument it should use my implementation, and for all other cases it should use the default impl. The result is not what I would expect though. If I call like like this:

```
constexpr use_my_impl_t use_my_impl;

foo(42, use_my_impl_t{});
foo(42, 2);
foo(42, use_my_impl);
```

it prints

```
Using my impl: 41
Using default impl: 43
Using default impl: 43
```

Why the last statement doesn't invoke my implementation despite an instance of `use_my_impl_t` being passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is what `T` is being deduced as.  In `foo(42, use_my_impl_t{});`, `use_my_impl_t{}` is an rvalue so `T` gets deduced as `use_my_impl_t` and the parameter becomes `use_my_impl_t&&`.

With `foo(42, use_my_impl);`, `use_my_impl` is an lvalue.  That means `T` is deduced as `use_my_impl_t &` to preserve that lvalueness. That means the parameter becomes `use_my_impl_t& &&` which [collapses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2) to `use_my_impl_t&`.

This is what is causing `std::is_same<T, use_my_impl_t>::value` not to work, since a `use_my_impl_t&` is not the same as a `use_my_impl_t`.  To fix this you can use `std::decay_t` to remove the reference and cv-qualification of the type.  That would give you

```
template<
    typename T,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, use_my_impl_t>::value>::type * = nullptr>
void foo(int i, T&& t)
{
    std::cout << "Using my impl: " << --i << std::endl;
}

template<
    typename T,
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, use_my_impl_t>::value>::type * = nullptr>
    void foo(int i, T&& t)
{
    std::cout << "Using default impl: " << ++i << std::endl;
}
```

which then outputs

```
Using my impl: 41
Using default impl: 43
Using my impl: 41
```

using your driver code.