# std::forward does not become conditional cast if there are no templates?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I've read many articles saying that if there are no templates for the function, `std::forward<>()` does not become a conditional cast anymore and just basically casts objects to RValue reference. Is that true?

Comment: i think you are confusing universal references with using `std::forward`. `std::forward` is always a cast, but a `T&&` parameter is different depending on `T` being a template parameter or not

Comment: What is a `conditional cast`?

Comment: If there's no template, you already know the value category and don't need help preserving it in a generic way, so `std::forward` won't help you. Of course you could still use it (it'll cast to whatever you tell it to), but for no benefit and the chance of using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

`std::forward` has a relatively simple implementation.  It could look like this:

```
template <typename T>
T&& forward( std::remove_reference_t<T> & param )
{
   return static_cast<T &&>(param);
}
```

As you can see, it's just a `static_cast`, and **not conditional**.  Given some type `T`, it casts the result to `T&&`.

If `T` is a value type like `std::string` or an r-value reference like `std::string&&`, the result will always be an r-value reference.

If `T` is an l-value reference like `std::string&`, you are effecively performing `static_cast<std::string& &&>(param)` and the rules of [*reference collapsing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747) will cast it to a l-value `std::string&`.

The reason that `std::forward` may feel like a conditional cast is because it is intended to be used with forwarding references.  Forwarding reference types are either **value types** or **l-value references**, depending on the calling context.

Comment: It is conditionally an identity cast or a cast to rvalue (with a possible implicit "cast" first)

Comment: Wait, let me get this straight, if T is a non-reference (eg. std::string, int), it is a RValue?

Comment: It is always cast to `T&&`.  `std::string` will be cast to `std::string &&`.

Comment: @Joanadivertos It is a prvalue, a special case of rvalue. That happen when the type of an expression is `T`, whithout reference. For example, `1` is int. But `int x =0; x;` then the expression `x;` is `int&`