# Why r-value becomes l-value?

Tags: c++

Due to the fact that the [general question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73213128/when-stdforward-converts-l-value-to-r-value) "how `std::forward` works" is too complicated I decided to start with a question on a particular example:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

namespace
{
    void foo(const int&)
    {
        std::cout << "const l-value" << std::endl;
    }

    void foo(int&)
    {
        std::cout << "l-value" << std::endl;
    }

    void foo(int&&)
    {
        std::cout << "r-value" << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void deduce(T&& x)
    {
        //foo(std::forward<T>(x));
        foo(x);
    }
}

int main()
{
    deduce(1);

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
l-value
```

Why?

We pass r-value and the argument of `deduce` is r-value, right? Why is `foo(int&)` called?

When I call directly

```
foo(1);
```

it prints `r-value`. When does it become l-value inside `deduce`?

**EDIT1**

If I add `foo2` to the code above:

```
void foo2(int&& val)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(val), int&&>);

    foo(val);
}
```

and then call it from main

```
foo2(1);
```

`l-value` is printed but not `r-value` as I probably expected.

So, as mentioned in comments and answers, `val` is l-value because it is a named variable and it does not matter if it is declared as `int&&` or `int&`. That is something that I did not know before.

Comment: The parameter is a universal reference. 'It has a name, so it is a lvalue.' http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_05.html

Comment: That's why perfect forwarding is required. There was/is a fault in the standard (C++11). So they invented perfect forwarding to fix that.

Comment: @digito_evo is not perfect forwarding from C++11?

Comment: @Alexey Starinsky It is. However mistakes were made back then.

Comment: "named variable" -> think of it as "locatable value"

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky this question should have the "language-lawyer" tag

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thing that everyone seems to be confused about when being introduced to this is that value category is not a property of an object, variable or other entity. It is not part of a type or anything, which makes it confusing because we also talk about *lvalue references* and *rvalue references* which are distinct concepts from value categories. Value category is a property of individual *expressions* only.

An *id-expression* like `x` or `val`, naming a variable, is always a lvalue expression, no matter what type the named variable has or whether it is a reference or whether it is a local/global variable or a function parameter or a template parameter, etc. The expression naming a variable of rvalue reference type is therefore still a lvalue expression.

And the second kind of property of expressions, their *types*, have references stripped. So the value category of the expression `x` (or `val`) is lvalue and its type is `int`, although the type of the *variable* named `x` (or `val`) is `int&&` (and doesn't have any value category).

A function call expression like `std::forward<T>(x)` in which the return type of the selected function is a rvalue reference is a xvalue expression (a kind of rvalue expression). And again, the expression's type is always non-reference, here `int`.

For a full list of the value categories of every kind of expression, see the lists at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category.

Comment: Probably I figured this out.  We can say that r-value `1` becomes l-value inside `deduce` because it gets name `x`. And the same with `foo2`, see EDIT1.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky I don't think it it helpful to say "become" here. The whole point is that value category is not a property of an object. It is not like anything changes about the object when it is passed to the function. `1` is just one expression and `x` is another, unrelated, expression. The former is a prvalue expression or a xvalue expression after temporary materialization and the latter is a lvalue expression. There is no connection between the two. That you are using the former as an argument for the function parameter named `x` is irrelevant.

Comment: How can you define the term `entity`?. Is there a definition in C++ standard?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#pre-3

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky It is not all that relevant here though. The relevant distinction is that a _variable_ can either be an _object_ or be a _reference_, which are not _objects_ themselves. (see [pre]/6) I think this notation might not be obvious and it might be unclear that the _object_ referred to by the _result_ of the expression `x` would have likely type `int`, although the _variable_ named in the expression `x` is of type `int&&`. I like to use the more general term _entity_ to (hopefully) make it clearer that I mean the type of the reference itself, not the object it references.

Comment: At least I probably understand that there is a difference between `x` variable type that is `int&&` and expression `x` that is `l-value`.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
    template <typename T>
    void deduce(T&& x)
```

may casually *look* like a RValue reference, however it is ***not*** a RValue reference.  (*I misunderstood this for years until I attended a class on Universal References recently*).  When used in this way it is a ***Universal Reference***.

*It's subtly yet another one of those double-meanings of operators that you see elsewhere in C++.... << >> | "inline" etc...*

See here for more detail: https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

This is an important snippet from there:

> Given that rvalue references are declared using “&&”, it seems reasonable to assume that the presence of “&&” in a type declaration indicates an rvalue reference. That is not the case:

> ```
> Widget&& var1 = someWidget;      // here, “&&” means rvalue reference
>
> auto&& var2 = var1;              // here, “&&” does not mean rvalue reference
>
> template<typename T>
> void f(std::vector<T>&& param);  // here, “&&” means rvalue reference
>
> template<typename T>
> void f(T&& param);               // here, “&&”does not mean rvalue reference
> ```

To further trip you up, C++20 has a feature called "abbreviated function templates", keep an eye out for this; the above template parameter could be written as follows:

```
    void deduce(auto&& x)
```

---

The other part of your question is "how does std::forward work".  Quintessentially, it works on the basis of "***reference collapsing***".  See a couple of articles here:

- [Concise explanation of reference collapsing rules requested: (1) A& & -> A& , (2) A& && -> A& , (3) A&& & -> A& , and (4) A&& && -> A&&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2)
- https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/xl-c-and-cpp-aix/13.1.2?topic=operators-reference-collapsing-c11

Comment: I also got the same effect with `void foo2(int&& val)`, see EDIT1

Comment: The "not an rvalue reference" thing doesn't sound right to me. It is one. It might ultimately resolve to an lvalue reference, but this is not unique to forwarding references, any rvalue references to dependent types (or just typedefs) can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the opposite: if it weren't 'change back'. In that case, if you were to use *two* `foo(x)` calls, the code would consider both times the `T&&` overload. Therefore, you couldn't specify *where* you can move from it.

Hence the standard is worded in a way that, when you write `std::forward<T>(x)`, you'll be able to move from it; otherwise, it's a reference (lvalue). Technically, you're searching for the terms lvalue and xvalue in the standard.