# What are the rules of rvalue(&&) lvalue(&) reference binding in templates with regard to reference collapsing?

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue, lvalue, reference-collapsing

Consider these cases:

```
int i{};
int& ir{i};

class A{
public:
    int& i;
    A(int&& pi):i(pi){}
};

A a1{i}; // Error // case 1
A a2{int(1)}; // OK // case 2

class B{
public:
    int& i;
    template<typename TYPE>
    B(TYPE&& pi):i(pi){}
};

B b1{i}; // OK // case 3
B b2{int(1)}; //OK // case 4
int& ii{int(12)}; // Error // case 5
int& iii{std::move(int(12))}; // Error // case 6

template<typename TYPE>
class C{
public:
    TYPE& i;
    C(TYPE&& pi):i(pi){}
};

C c1{i}; // Error // case 7
C c2{int(1)}; // OK // case 8
C<int&> c3{i}; // OK // case 9
C<int&> c4{int(1)}; // Error // case 10
int&& iiii{ir}; // Error // case 11
```

A rvalue can not be bound to lvalue and if my understanding is correct, `TYPE&&` would either collapse to `TYPE&&` or `TYPE&`.
How ever I am having a hard time understanding these cases, specially case 4. If case 4 is correct, then it means we have `b2.i` which is a reference, initialized from a temporary (rvalue). Then why case 2, 5, 6 and 7 are incorrect? And when case 9 is correct it mean the `TYPE&&` is `int&&&` which (I assume) collapses to `int&` , then how could `c3.i` which is an rvalue(`int&&`) be initialized from a lvalue, while case 10 and 11 are incorrect?

I wish some one could explain the general rules regarding this subject and also these cases in detail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concise explanation of reference collapsing rules requested: (1) A& & -> A& , (2) A& && -> A& , (3) A&& & -> A& , and (4) A&& && -> A&&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several mechanisms at play here: lvalue/rvalue semantics, reference collapsing, forwarding reference and CTAD. I think explaining the cases you listed should be sufficient to form a big picture.

1. rvalue reference `int&& pi` can't be bound to lvalue `i`.
2. rvalue reference `int&& pi` can be bound to rvalue `int(1)`. `pi` in `i(pi)` refers to a memory location so it is an lvalue, allowing `a2.i` to be initialized. After construction `a2.i` is a dangling reference to `int(1)`.
3. forwarding reference `TYPE&& pi` can be bound to lvalue `i`. `TYPE` is `int&`. `b1.i` refers to `i`.
4. forwarding reference `TYPE&& pi` can be bound to rvalue `int(1)`. `TYPE` is `int`. `TYPE&& pi` is an rvalue reference, similar to case 2 `b2.i` is a dangling reference to `int(1)`.
5. lvalue reference `int& ii` can not be bound to rvalue `int(12)`.
6. lvalue reference `int& iii` can not be bound to rvalue `std::move(int(12))`.

In cases 7-10 `TYPE&& pi` is not a forwarding reference because `TYPE` is a template parameter of `class C`, not of constructor. CTAD, used in 7-8 to deduce `TYPE`, doesn't change that: an rvalue is expected, only then `TYPE` can be deduced to `int`, forming `int&& pi`.

7. `TYPE` can't be deduced.
8. `TYPE` is deduced to be `int`. `c2.i`, declared as `int& i;`, forms a dangling reference to `int(1)`.
9. `TYPE` is explicitly `int&`. `TYPE&& pi` is collapsed to `int& pi`. `TYPE& i` is collapsed to `int& i`. `c3.i` refers to `i`.
10. `TYPE&& pi` is collapsed to `int& pi`, lvalue reference can't be bound to `int(1)`.
11. rvalue reference `int&& iiii` can't be bound to lvalue `ir`.

And a bonus case that might make cases 2 and 4 easier to understand:

```cpp
int&& rvr = 1;
int&& rvr2 = rvr;
```

The first line is correct, the last is an error. `int&& rvr` is an rvalue reference and extends lifetime of a temporary. But `rvr` mentioned in the last line is an lvalue, so rvalue reference `int&& rvr2` can't be bound to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I wish you could explain more. In case 9, when the ```TYPE``` parameter of the class template is determined as ```int&``` then why ```TYPE&&``` in the constructor can differ from ```int&&``` and collapses to int&?

Comment: @AKL, `TYPE&&` is `int& &&`, and rvalue reference to lvalue reference collapses to lvalue reference. Only rvalue reference to rvalue reference collapses to rvalue reference.