# when will there be && + && -> && with c++ reference collapse?

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer, reference-collapsing

I have some question about understanding reference collapse, so I do experiments in the following code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void func(T&& t) {}


int main() {
    // There is no reference collapse here, only binding left or right values to
    // references with universal reference:
    int a = 10;
    func(a); // this equals func<int>(a)
    func(10); // what does this equal to?
    func(std::move(a)); // what does this equal to?

    // The following is not case of universal reference, they are reference
    // collapse, only that the type is template type:
    int& b1 = a;
    int&& b2 = 10;

    // this is the collapse of & + && -> &
    func(b1); // this equals func<int&>(b1)

    // this is the collapse of & + && -> &, since b2 is left reference here not
    // right reference:
    func(b2); // this equals func<int&&>(b2)
}
```

Am I correct on understanding the above code? Would you please show me the case of collapsing `&& + && -> &&` ?

Comment: See also: [What are the reference collapsing rules, and how are they utilized by the C++ standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/what-are-the-reference-collapsing-rules-and-how-are-they-utilized-by-the-c-st)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some misunderstanding with [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references). When being passed lvalues to `func`, the template parameter `T` will be deduced as lvalue-reference; for rvalues `T` will be deduced as non-reference type. I.e.

```
int a = 10;
func(a);  // T is deduced as int&, then int& && -> int& is the type of parameter t
func(10); // T is deduced as int, then int&& is the type of parameter t
func(std::move(a)); // T is deduced as int, then int&& is the type of parameter t

int& b1 = a;
int&& b2 = 10;
func(b1); // T is deduced as int&, then int& && -> int& is the type of parameter t
func(b2); // T is deduced as int&, then int& && -> int& is the type of parameter t. Note that b2 is an lvalue
```

> Would you please show me the case of collapsing && + && -> && ?

You can

```
func<int&&>(0); // T is specified as int&&, then int&& && -> int&& is the type of parameter t
```

Comment: Why doesn't `func(b2)` equal to `func<int&&>(b2)`?

Comment: Also, reference collapse has nothing to do with the rule of universal reference, is this correct?

Comment: @coincheung As I explained, `b2` is an lvalue (even its type is rvalue-reference, see more about [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)), then `func(b2)` is same as `func<int&>(b2)` according to forwarding reference rule.

Comment: @coincheung Yes they're two independent rules. In the invocation of `func`, the final result comes from the interaction of these 2 rules.

Comment: " When being passed lvalues to func, the template parameter T will be deduced as lvalue-reference; for rvalues T will be deduced as non-reference type". Is this is core or universal reference? This always works in the case of `template<typename T> void func(T&&) {}`, right? and it also works in the case of  `template<typename T> void func(T&) {}` ?

Comment: @coincheung No, it's only for universal reference (i.e. forwarding reference).

Comment: Would you please show me a case of `&& + & -> &` ?

Comment: @coincheung Not `& + && -> &`? Maybe `template<typename T> void func(T&) {}`, then `func<int&&>(a);`, the parameter type would be `&& + & -> &`.

Comment: What is the rule of this: `template <typename T> void func(T&);`, if I call with `func(a)` and `func(10)`  ?

Comment: @coincheung No difference here. `T` will be deduced as `int` and parameter type will be `int&` for both cases. Then `func(10);` will fail.

Comment: Why not `T` will be deduced into `int&` when call `func(a)`, and what is the process of deducing when calling `func(10);` ? In universal reference, `func(a)` is deduced into `func(int& &&)`, but non-universal reference, it will be `func(int &)`, not `func(int& &)`?

Comment: It's just how *normal* template deduction works, template parameter won't be deduced as reference type. For your 2nd question, as `T` is deduced as `int`, then parameter type would be `int&`. No reference collapse here.

Comment: One more question, deduction only happens when calling without `<>` to assign type. For example, `func(a)` will trigger deduction, but `func<int>` or `func<int&>` or `func<int&&>()` will not trigger type deduction. Am I correct on this?

Comment: @coincheung Yes, when you specify template argument explicitly, template deduction won't happen.

Answer (score 3):

Your examples for collapsing aren't actually reference collapsing. Template argument deduction of forwarding references (that *all* of your examples actually do rely on) uses different verbiage that is parallel to, but not dependent on reference collapsing.

`std::add_rvalue_reference` and `std::add_lvalue_reference` are the prime examples for reference collapsing.

```
std::add_rvalue_reference<int&>::type x = ...; // x is a lvalue reference & + && = &
std::add_rvalue_reference<int&&>::type y = ...; // y is a rvalue reference && + && = &&
```

The standard verbiage is is over at [[dcl.ref]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#6):

> If a typedef-name ([dcl.typedef], [temp.param]) or a decltype-specifier ([dcl.type.decltype]) denotes a type TR that is a reference to a type T, an attempt to create the type “lvalue reference to cv TR” creates the type “lvalue reference to T”, while an attempt to create the type “rvalue reference to cv TR” creates the type TR.
>
> [Note 3: This rule is known as reference collapsing. — end note]