Unable to access template class specialization through universal reference
I was using forwarding references in my code when I encountered something that I don't understand.
Example Code
To illustrate the phenomenon I wrote this simplified version of my scenario:
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Cls
{
    static void func(T& b)
    {
        std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    }
};

template <>
struct Cls<int>
{
    static void func(int& b)
    {
        std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
void some_func(T&& a)
{
    Cls<T>::func(a);
}

int main()
{
    int i{3};
    some_func(i);
    some_func(3);
}

My Understanding
My understanding of a universal references is that they can be either an lvalue or an rvalue.
(A) In my head, this means that the first call (some_func(i);) should access a version of the function where the type of a is T& (in this particular case: int&), since the passed variable i is an lvalue of type int. Because T is int, and since there is a specialized function Cls<int>::func(int&), there should be a match and output should be 2.
(B) The second call (some_func(3);) should access a version where the type of a is T&& (in this case: int&&). I was not entirely sure what the output here would be.
The actual output I got was:
> 1
> 2

Note that the behaviour is the same even for non-primitive types T.
Questions

Does the compiler instantiate different versions of some_func() depending on passed reference types? I.e., one for some_func(int& a) and one for some_func(int&& a)? Or is it actually some sort of new reference type within the same instantiated function?
Why is the first output 1? Why is the specialization not used? Is my interpretation in (A) incorrect? In any case T should be int, so how is the generic implementation selected instead when they are otherwise identical?
Why is the second output 2? Considering that the first call was unable to match with the specialization when the types are identical (int&), why should it be able to match when there is a mismatch (int& and int&&)?
Has this got something to do with the fact that a is an xvalue in both cases? I.e., that the rvalue may be interpreted as an lvalue because it is intermediately stored in a? This would explain why the second call outputs 2, but not why the first call does not?

Thanks in advance.

In the first call, T resolves to int&. The type of a is int& && which collapes to int&. Since int& != int, the primary template is called.

In the second call, T resolves to int. The type of a is int&&. Cls<T> then resoles to Cls<int> specialization.

Yes, the program call two different instantiations of some_func, namely some_func<int&> and some_func<int>

Possible partial dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/what-are-the-reference-collapsing-rules-and-how-are-they-utilized-by-the-c-st

Minor correction: a universal references can be either a reference to an lvalue or a reference to an rvalue.

Note that in your code Cls<T>::func(a); the argument a is always an lvalue reference and that's why functions taking lvalue reference are matched in both cases. In order to actually forward the reference you would need to use std::forward<T>(a), in which case the code wouldn't compile because there is no overload for rvalue argument.
The type T in template <typename T> void some_func(T&& a); is deduced as int& for the first call some_func(i); resulting in primary template instantiation Cls<int&>. And in the function static void func(T& b) the references are collapsed resulting in int& argument type.
In the second call some_func(3) the type T is deduced as int and therefore the specialization Cls<int> is selected, and static void func(int& b) is called as there is a direct match of the argument.
Here is a demo for all three cases.
